# Django: Select data from already existed tables

Tags: mysql, django

I am new to the world of Django. I am developing an application which will manipulate data on some new tables and some others that are already existed. Until now I knew how to create a new model and when I issue the ..syncdb command a corresponding, to the model, table will be created.

The other tables are used from another (not mine) application. How do you believe is the best way to proceed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation has a whole page on [dealing with legacy databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/legacy-databases/), including how to autogenerate your models from the existing database.